# How does the tense affect the meaning of a construction with “sobald”?

Tags: conjunction, tense

Hello there im learning German and I have read these three sentences that were built with *Temporalen Konnektoren* and the case here is with *sobald* (“unmittelbare Abfolge”):

1. > Sobald Paula eine neue Arbeit gefunden hatte, ist sie nach Berlin umgezogen.
2. > Sobald Paula eine neue Arbeit gefunden hat, zieht sie nach Berlin um.
3. > Sobald Paula eine neue Arbeit findet, zieht sie nach Berlin um.

Please explain the difference in the meaning between these as I understood that *sobald* means “die Bedeutung wird als Zukunft gerechnet”.

Answer (score 8):

*Sobald* tells a condition for an immediately following event.

> Sobald Paula eine neue Arbeit gefunden hatte, ist sie nach Berlin umgezogen.

The first clause is in *Plusquamperfekt*, the second clause in *Perfekt*. So both finding a job and immediately moving to Berlin after that event happened in the past.

> Sobald Paula eine neue Arbeit gefunden hat, zieht sie nach Berlin um.

First clause is in *Perfekt*, second in *Präsens*. Paula is looking for a new job at the moment, but it takes its time. Moving to Berlin will follow immediately as soon that condition is met.

> Sobald Paula eine neue Arbeit findet, zieht sie nach Berlin um.

Both clauses are in *Präsens*. Finding a job and moving to Berlin happen in the near future. This is a general statement about Paula's plans.